# Can I add custom fields or values to existing metadata objects?

Tags: lightning-web-components, custom-metadata

Our app allows users to select Lightning components to populate our legacy "widget" framework. Yes, I know we could redesign the product to use Lightning pages, but we're not doing that right now. I want to add information to Lightning web components (the Lightning Component Bundle) to indicate whether or not a particular component should be visible to our widget framework, something like:

```
<LightningComponentBundle...>
  <isExposedToOurWidgetFramework>true</isExposedToOurWidgetFramework>
```

or

```
  <targets>
    <target>ourProduct__WidgetFramework</target
```

Of course, when I do this I get an error about an invalid TARGETS. Is there any approach to doing this?

Comment: I am confused. How are you importing the LWC into your framework? Why don't you pass an `@api` value and use `if:true={isExposed}` to control the visibility?

Comment: You can't extend the metadata to add extra "annotations" of your own. I suggest you provide an explicit catalog or use a specific component naming convention to handle this.

Comment: @PhilW Thank you. We will figure out some other way.

Comment: @Arthlete Thank you for your comment. We are retrieving the names of available LWCs via an Apex method we wrote for that purpose. We can obviously see `isExposed` on them, but there are some component we want to make available to Lightning pages but not to our proprietary layout machinery, and vice  versa.